# How to change order by condition in cursor based on some value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is my problem.

```
if ord = 'd' then
   Ordby:= 'name'
else
   Ordby:= 'type'.
end if;
declare cursor file is
  select type,name,location, from filemstr order by ordby;
  begin
    for i in file
    loop
  end;
```

Problem is order by ordby is not working. It always ordering by default. Is that possible to use a variable to order?  I need to order this on the following condition. I don't want to declare cursor two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare cursor file is
  select type,name,location, from filemstr order by decode(ord,'d',name,type)
  begin
    for i in file
    loop
  end;
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is one of two valid approaches, the other being dynamic SQL via EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Comment: I didn't DV (and whoever did can't seem to make up their mind), but some explanation might be useful?

Comment: Doesn't ord needs to be a (cursor) parameter for this to work?

Comment: @Sathya - only if it is out of scope, which ins't likely to be the case here.

Comment: @Alex slightly weird to see a cursor declaration after an if statement, without enclosing anon. block in the question...

Comment: @Sathya - yes, so I assume it's part of a larger block which isn't all shown; with a nested declare/begin/end. Which is unnecessary, but the OP might have thought it was needed to make `Ordby` in-scope for the cursor. They can be declared at the same level. ([It works either way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/32246))